# Navigate the UI using only keyboard

Tags: angularjs, navigation, keypress, angular-ui

I'm trying to navigate thru a list of records using only keyboard. When the page loads, the default "focus" should be on the first record, when the user clicks the down arrow on the keyboard, the next record needs to be focused. When the user clicks the up arrow, the previous record should be focused. When the user clicks the Enter button, it should take them to the details page of that record.

[Here's what I have so far on Plunkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/mTeMgAHPgYx1Kvi2fMTW)

It appears that this is supported in AngularJS in 1.1.5 (unstable), which we can't use in production. I'm currently using 1.0.7. I'm hoping to do something like this - the key should be handled at the document level. When the user presses a certain key, the code should look up in an array of allowed keys. If a  match is found (e.g. down key code), it should move the focus (apply the .highlight css) to the next element. When enter is pressed, it should grab the record which .highlight css and get the record id for further processing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

Here is the example what you could choose to do: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/XRGPYCk6auOxmylMe0Uu?p=preview

```
<body key-trap>
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="record in records">
      <div class="record"
           ng-class="{'record-highlight': record.navIndex == focu sIndex}">
        {{ record.name }}
      </div>
    </li>
  </div>
</body>
```

This is the simplest approach I could think of.
It binds a directive `keyTrap` to the `body` which catches the `keydown` event and
`$broadcast` message to child scopes.
The element holder scope will catch the message and simply increment or decrement the
focusIndex or fire an `open` function if hitting `enter`.

## EDIT

http://plnkr.co/edit/rwUDTtkQkaQ0dkIFflcy?p=preview

now supports, ordered / filtered list.

Event handling part has not changed, but now uses `$index` and also filtered list caching
technique combined to track which item is getting focused.

Comment: It is a nice approach, but it doesn't work when the entries are ordered (`record in records | orderBy: '-name'`). Do you have a solution for that, too? (not just for this case but a more generic one)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  It is always fun and preasure to be challenged with more difficult use cases.  I add the additional code which supports sorted/filtered list.

Comment: this makes it that clicking all keys does not do default behavior. for example f5 does not refresh. anyway to fix this?

Comment: @AryehArmon I tested my plunker page with chrome and F5 does refresh.  My understanding is that if you run `event.preventDefault()` then default key binding (e.g. F5) would be canceled, otherwise F5 should work.  I suggest you to load jQuery instead of using jqLite (which is part of Angular).

Answer (score 5):

All of the solutions offered up so far have a single common problem. The directives are not reusable, they require knowledge of variables created in the parent $scope provided by the controller. That means if you wanted to use the same directive in a different view you would need to re-implement everything you did the previous controller and ensure you are using the same variable names for things, since the directives basically have hard coded $scope variable names in them.  You definitely wouldn’t be able to use the same directive twice within the same parent scope.

The way around this is to use isolated scope in the directive. By doing this you can make the directive reusable regardless of the parent $scope by generically parameterizing items required from the parent scope.

In my solution the only thing that the controller needs to do is provide a selectedIndex variable that the directive uses to track which row in the table is currently selected. I could have isolated the responsibility of this variable to the directive but by making the controller provide the variable it allows you to manipulate the currently selected row in the table outside of the directive. For example you could implement “on click select row” in your controller while still using the arrow keys for navigation in the directive.

The Directive:

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('cdArrowTable', cdArrowTable);
    .directive('cdArrowRow', cdArrowRow);

function cdArrowTable() {
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        scope: {
            collection: '=cdArrowTable',
            selectedIndex: '=selectedIndex',
            onEnter: '&onEnter'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            // Ensure the selectedIndex doesn't fall outside the collection
            scope.$watch('collection.length', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (scope.selectedIndex > newValue - 1) {
                    scope.selectedIndex = newValue - 1;
                } else if (oldValue <= 0) {
                    scope.selectedIndex = 0;
                }
            });

            element.bind('keydown', function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 38) {  // Up Arrow
                    if (scope.selectedIndex == 0) {
                        return;
                    }
                    scope.selectedIndex--;
                    e.preventDefault();
                } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {  // Down Arrow
                    if (scope.selectedIndex == scope.collection.length - 1) {
                        return;
                    }
                    scope.selectedIndex++;
                    e.preventDefault();
                } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {  // Enter
                    if (scope.selectedIndex >= 0) {
                        scope.collection[scope.selectedIndex].wasHit = true;
                        scope.onEnter({row: scope.collection[scope.selectedIndex]});
                    }
                    e.preventDefault();
                }

                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
}

function cdArrowRow($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            row: '=cdArrowRow',
            selectedIndex: '=selectedIndex',
            rowIndex: '=rowIndex',
            selectedClass: '=selectedClass',
            enterClass: '=enterClass',
            enterDuration: '=enterDuration'  // milliseconds
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctr) {
            // Apply provided CSS class to row for provided duration
            scope.$watch('row.wasHit', function(newValue) {
                if (newValue === true) {
                    element.addClass(scope.enterClass);
                    $timeout(function() { scope.row.wasHit = false;}, scope.enterDuration);
                } else {
                    element.removeClass(scope.enterClass);
                }
            });

            // Apply/remove provided CSS class to the row if it is the selected row.
            scope.$watch('selectedIndex', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue === scope.rowIndex) {
                    element.addClass(scope.selectedClass);
                } else if (oldValue === scope.rowIndex) {
                    element.removeClass(scope.selectedClass);
                }
            });

            // Handles applying/removing selected CSS class when the collection data is filtered.
            scope.$watch('rowIndex', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue === scope.selectedIndex) {
                    element.addClass(scope.selectedClass);
                } else if (oldValue === scope.selectedIndex) {
                    element.removeClass(scope.selectedClass);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This directive not only allows you to navigate a table using the arrow keys but it allows you to bind a callback method to the Enter key. So that when the enter key is pressed the row that is currently selected will be included as an argument to the callback method registered with the directive (onEnter).

As a little bit of an added bonus you can also pass a CSS class and duration to the cdArrowRow directive so that when the enter key is hit on a selected row the CSS class passed in will be applied to the row element then removed after the passed in duration (in milliseconds). This basically allows you to do something like making the row flash a different color when the enter key is hit.

View Usage:

```
<table cd-arrow-table="displayedCollection"
       selected-index="selectedIndex"
       on-enter="addToDB(row)">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in displayedCollection" 
            cd-arrow-row="row" 
            selected-index="selectedIndex" 
            row-index="$index" 
            selected-class="'mySelcetedClass'" 
            enter-class="'myEnterClass'" 
            enter-duration="150"
        >
            <td>{{row.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('MyController', myController);

    function myController($scope) {
        $scope.selectedIndex = 0;
        $scope.displayedCollection = [
            {firstName:"John", lastName: "Smith"},
            {firstName:"Jane", lastName: "Doe"}
        ];
        $scope.addToDB;

        function addToDB(item) {
            // Do stuff with the row data
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the directive below that I had once build for a similar problem. 
This directive listens to the keyboard events and changes the row selection.

This link has a complete explanation on how to build it. [Change row selection using arrows](http://code.ciphertrick.com/2015/03/15/change-row-selection-using-arrows-in-ng-repeat/).

Here is the directive

```
foodApp.directive('arrowSelector',['$document',function($document){
return{
    restrict:'A',
    link:function(scope,elem,attrs,ctrl){
        var elemFocus = false;             
        elem.on('mouseenter',function(){
            elemFocus = true;
        });
        elem.on('mouseleave',function(){
            elemFocus = false;
        });
        $document.bind('keydown',function(e){
            if(elemFocus){
                if(e.keyCode == 38){
                    console.log(scope.selectedRow);
                    if(scope.selectedRow == 0){
                        return;
                    }
                    scope.selectedRow--;
                    scope.$apply();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                if(e.keyCode == 40){
                    if(scope.selectedRow == scope.foodItems.length - 1){
                        return;
                    }
                    scope.selectedRow++;
                    scope.$apply();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

}]);

```
<table class="table table-bordered" arrow-selector>....</table>
```

And your repeater

```
     <tr ng-repeat="item in foodItems" ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}">
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement to support UI navigation using arrow keys. What I finally came up with is DOM's `keydown` event handler encapsulated within an AngularJS directive:

HTML:

```html
<ul ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="record in records">
        <div focusable tag="record" on-key="onKeyPressed" class="record">
            {{ record.name }}
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```css
.record {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.record:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    outline: none;
}
```

JS:

```js
module.directive('focusable', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.attr('tabindex', '-1'); // make it focusable

            var tag = attrs.tag ? scope.$eval(attrs.tag) : undefined; // get payload if defined
            var onKeyHandler = attrs.onKey ? scope.$eval(attrs.onKey) : undefined;

            element.bind('keydown', function (event) {
                var target = event.target;
                var key = event.which;

                if (isArrowKey(key)) {
                    var nextFocused = getNextElement(key); // determine next element that should get focused
                    if (nextFocused) {
                        nextFocused.focus();
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    }
                }
                else if (onKeyHandler) {
                    var keyHandled = scope.$apply(function () {
                        return onKeyHandler.call(target, key, tag);
                    });

                    if (keyHandled) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
});

function MainCtrl ($scope, $element) {
    $scope.onKeyPressed = function (key, record) {
        if (isSelectionKey(key)) {
            process(record);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

    $element.children[0].focus(); // focus first record
}
```

Comment: @SidBhalke, `isArrowKey()` determines if an arrow key has been pressed, i.e. `key >= 37 && key <= 40`. The function `getNextElement()` returns the element to be focused based on the key direction and your navigation logic. It might be hardcoded switch cases, or in general search for nearest element using its `getBoundingClientRect()`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27956752/how-to-select-next-previous-rows-column-on-keydown-event
...can u please see this link,

Answer (score 1):

You could create a table navigation service which tracks the current row and exposes navigation methods to modify the current row's value and sets focus to the row.

Then all you would need to do is create a key binding directive where you could track key down events and fire the exposed methods from the table navigation service, on key up or key down.

I have used a controller to link the service methods to the key binding directive via a configuration object called 'keyDefinitions'.

You can extend the keyDefinitions to include the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key (Code: 13) and hook on to the selected $index value via the service property 'tableNavigationService.currentRow' or '$scope.data', then pass it as a parameter to your own custom submit() function.

I hope that this is helpful to somebody.

I have posted my solution to this issue at the following plunker location:

[Keyboard Navigation Service Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/PHGJ3AxNVU1wkIDueGLW?p=preview)

HTML:

```
<div key-watch>
  <table st-table="rowCollection" id="tableId" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th st-sort="firstName">first name</th>
        <th st-sort="lastName">last name</th>
        <th st-sort="birthDate">birth date</th>
        <th st-sort="balance" st-skip-natural="true">balance</th>
        <th>email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <!-- ADD CONDITIONAL STYLING WITH ng-class TO ASSIGN THE selected CLASS TO THE ACTIVE ROW -->
      <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection track by $index" tabindex="{{$index + 1}}" ng-class="{'selected': activeRowIn($index)}">
        <td>{{row.firstName | uppercase}}</td>
        <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{row.birthDate | date}}</td>
        <td>{{row.balance | currency}}</td>
        <td>
          <a ng-href="mailto:{{row.email}}">email</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
  app.controller('navigationDemoController', [
    '$scope',
    'tableNavigationService',
    navigationDemoController
  ]);

  function navigationDemoController($scope, tableNavigationService) {
    $scope.data = tableNavigationService.currentRow;

    $scope.keyDefinitions = {
      'UP': navigateUp,
      'DOWN': navigateDown
    }

    $scope.rowCollection = [
      {
        firstName: 'Chris',
        lastName: 'Oliver',
        birthDate: '1980-01-01',
        balance: 100,
        email: 'chris@email.com'
      },
      {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Smith',
        birthDate: '1976-05-25',
        balance: 100,
        email: 'chris@email.com'
      },
      {
        firstName: 'Eric',
        lastName: 'Beatson',
        birthDate: '1990-06-11',
        balance: 100,
        email: 'chris@email.com'
      },
      {
        firstName: 'Mike',
        lastName: 'Davids',
        birthDate: '1968-12-14',
        balance: 100,
        email: 'chris@email.com'
      }
    ];

    $scope.activeRowIn = function(index) {
      return index === tableNavigationService.currentRow;
    };

    function navigateUp() {
      tableNavigationService.navigateUp();
    };

    function navigateDown() {
      tableNavigationService.navigateDown();
    };

    function init() {
      tableNavigationService.setRow(0);
    };

    init();
  };
})();
```

SERVICE AND DIRECTIVE:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  var app = angular.module('tableNavigation', []);

  app.service('tableNavigationService', [
    '$document',
    tableNavigationService
  ]);
  app.directive('keyWatch', [
    '$document',
    keyWatch
  ]);

  // TABLE NAVIGATION SERVICE FOR NAVIGATING UP AND DOWN THE TABLE
  function tableNavigationService($document) {
    var service = {};

    // Your current selected row
    service.currentRow = 0;
    service.table = 'tableId';
    service.tableRows = $document[0].getElementById(service.table).getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');

    // Exposed method for navigating up
    service.navigateUp = function () {
        if (service.currentRow) {
            var index = service.currentRow - 1;

            service.setRow(index);
        }
    };

    // Exposed method for navigating down
    service.navigateDown = function () {
        var index = service.currentRow + 1;

        if (index === service.tableRows.length) return;

        service.setRow(index);
    };

    // Expose a method for altering the current row and focus on demand
    service.setRow = function (i) {
        service.currentRow = i;
        scrollRow(i);
    }

    // Set focus to the active table row if it exists
    function scrollRow(index) {
        if (service.tableRows[index]) {
            service.tableRows[index].focus();
        }
    };

    return service;
  };

  // KEY WATCH DIRECTIVE TO MONITOR KEY DOWN EVENTS
  function keyWatch($document) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope) {
        $document.unbind('keydown').bind('keydown', function(event) {
          var keyDefinitions = scope.keyDefinitions;
          var key = '';

          var keys = {
              UP: 38,
              DOWN: 40,
          };

          if (event && keyDefinitions) {

            for (var k in keys) {
              if (keys.hasOwnProperty(k) && keys[k] === event.keyCode) {
                  key = k;
              }
            }

            if (!key) return;

            var navigationFunction = keyDefinitions[key];

            if (!navigationFunction) {
              console.log('Undefined key: ' + key);
              return;
            }

              event.preventDefault();
                scope.$apply(navigationFunction());
                return;
          }
          return;
        });
      }
    }
  }
})();
```