# How to select next & previous rows column,on keydown event

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

Consider I am on the nth row & n-th column(xyz1), when I press 'down arrow key' it should change the background color of next rows n-th column, similarly when i press 'Up arrow key' it should change the background color of previous rows n-th column.

I tried but background color is not applying, what i need to do ?

HTML::

```
 div class="row col-md-10">
 <div class="col-md-3 " style="background-color: #dedef8" >Name</div>
 <div class='col-md-3' style="background-color: #dedef8">adress</div>
 <div class='col-md-3' style="background-color: #dedef8">phone</div>
 <div class='col-md-3' style="background-color: #dedef8">email</div>
</div>
<div class="row col-md-10">
<div  ng-repeat='d in data' ng-init="sectionIndex = $index">
  <div class='col-md-3' ng-keydown="IamDowm($event)" style="background-color: #dedec2" focus ng-enter inx='{{sectionIndex}}'   tabindex="-1">{{d.a}}</div>
  <div class='col-md-3' ng-keydown="IamDowm($event)" style="background-color: #dedec2" focus ng-enter  inx='{{sectionIndex}}' tabindex="-1">{{d.b}}</div>
  <div class='col-md-3'  ng-keydown="IamDowm($event)"style="background-color: #dedec2" focus  ng-enter  inx='{{sectionIndex}}' tabindex="-1">{{d.c}}</div>
  <div class='col-md-3'ng-keydown="IamDowm($event)"  style="background-color: #dedec2" focus ng-enter  inx='{{sectionIndex}}' tabindex="-1">{{d.d}}</div>
```

Angular Directive:

```
sidapp.directive('ngEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {

            if(event.which === 39) {
                 var target = $(event.target).next();
                $(target).trigger('focus');
                 $(target).next().css('background-color', 'red');
                //event.preventDefault();
            }else if(event.which === 37){
                   var target = $(event.target).prev();
                $(target).trigger('focus');
                console.log($(target));
                 $(target).prev().css('background-color', 'green');
            }else if(event.which === 40){
               var target = $(event.target).parent().siblings('div').eq(parseInt(attrs.inx));
                $(target).eq(0).css('background-color', 'blue');
                console.log( $(event.target));
                console.log(target);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working Example FOR HTML TABLES**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raypzm

```
$('table#hi tbody tr').first().addClass('red');

$(document).keyup(function(event) {
    var pressed = event.key;

    if (pressed == 'Down') {
        var lastCheck = $('table#hi tbody tr').last().hasClass('red');
        if (lastCheck) return;
        else $('table#hi tbody tr.red').removeClass('red').next().addClass('red');
    }

    if (pressed == 'Up') {
        var firstCheck = $('table#hi tbody tr').first().hasClass('red');
        if (firstCheck) return;
        else $('table#hi tbody tr.red').removeClass('red').prev().addClass('red');
    }
});
```

**Example For DIVS**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emvPwx

```
$('div#hi div').first().addClass('red');

$(document).keyup(function(event) {
    var pressed = event.key;

    if (pressed == 'Down') {
        var lastCheck = $('div#hi div').last().hasClass('red');
        if (lastCheck) return;
        else $('div#hi div.red').removeClass('red').next().addClass('red');
    }

    if (pressed == 'Up') {
        var firstCheck = $('div#hi div').first().hasClass('red');
        if (firstCheck) return;
        else $('div#hi div.red').removeClass('red').prev().addClass('red');
    }
});
```

Comment: when html in table format works but how can i achieve in Div's

Comment: Same concept just add a parent DIV select child divs

Comment: @rafal : can you please cross check ur demo is not working on codeopen.

Comment: @SidBhalke I just did...it's working as it should.  Make sure you are click the html body and then use your keyboard to navigate

Answer (score 1):

Finally I fixed by using chidren().eq('colNumber')

```
app.directive('ngEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {

            if(event.which === 39) {
                 var target = $(event.target).next();
                $(target).trigger('focus');
                //event.preventDefault();
            }else if(event.which === 37){
                   var target = $(event.target).prev();
                $(target).trigger('focus');

                 //  $(target).prev().css('background-color', 'green');
            }else if(event.which === 40){
                var target = $(event.target).parent();
                $(target).next().children().eq($(event.target)[0].id).focus();
                //$(target).next().children().eq($(event.target)[0].id).css('background-color', 'blue');

            } else if(event.which === 38){
                var target = $(event.target).parent();
                $(target).prev().children().eq($(event.target)[0].id).focus();
                //$(target).prev().children().eq($(event.target)[0].id).css('background-color', 'yellow');
            }
        });
    };
});
```