# angular2: how to control the whole app with keyboard only?

Tags: javascript, angular, spotlight, enyo

What approach would you recommend to control the whole app with keyboard only? I found [Spotlight](http://enyojs.com/sampler/latest/spotlight/index.html) lib, but it depends on enyojs which seems to have its own component model and overall enyojs seems to be an overkill.

So far I'm listening on keydown events in `app.component.ts`:

```
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event']) onKeydown(event: any) {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.mainKeydownHandler.handle(event.keyCode);
}
```

Each component which want to handle keydown events registers to `MainKeydownHandler`'s handlers and when keydown event occures `MainKeydownHandler` delegates an event to the registered handler. The appropriate handler is determined by `document.activeElement`'s class (I did not find more "angular2-like" way to get currently focused elem) in `MainKeydownHandler`'s handle method. So now I have to add appropriate class name to a group of elements I want to be able to focus.

Furthermore, component's handler gets all selectable elements with:

```
@ViewChildren('selectable') elements: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

so I need to add `#selectable` and class with ID of handler to each element I want to focus. Component's handler then receives `keyCode` and determines which element to select next, or return to previouslly selected elem from another component and so on.

This approach seems awkward, involves quite a lot of code when new component want to handle keydown events and there are situations when a component completely loses focus: when I delete an item from some list and then this component is rerendered (some service or `MainKeydownHandler` could remember, but this could lead to quite a lot of elements to remember along the way navigating user through components).

**Is there a better, simpler, more generic and more declarative way to control entire angular2 app with keyboard-only (keydown/keyup events)?**

**Alternatively, is it reasonable to use Spotlight (with enyojs dep.) with angular2 for this use-case? And can you provide working plunker with angular2+spotlight.** I could not get these two to work together.

Comment: Do you want to navigate around elements with keyboard or have some custom actions in response to keyboard events as in a game?

Comment: just navigation (up, down, right, left) and select (enter)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enable basic keyboard navigation, you can do it with `tabindex` which is a standard way of doing it. See the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute)

```js
document.getElementById('mylist').focus();
```

```css
:focus{
  border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
Press TAB to navigate.
<ul id="mylist" tabindex="-1">
    <li tabindex="1"> One </li>
    <li tabindex="2"> Two </li>
    <li tabindex="4"> Four </li>
    <li tabindex="3"> Three </li>
</ul>
```

If you want to do it with arrow keys, you will have to listen to `keydown` event on the document and manually `focus()` the elements using javascript. It will be easier to navigate back and forth, not that direct to find the element that is above and below current element in layout. You will have to compare x,y coordinates or offsets.

```js
document.getElementById('mylist').focus();

window.onkeydown = function(e) {
  var curr = document.activeElement;
  var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
    document.body,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,
    { acceptNode: function(node) { return (node.tabIndex === -1)?NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP: NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT} },
    false
);
  treeWalker.currentNode = curr;
  
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
     treeWalker.nextNode().focus();
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
     treeWalker.previousNode().focus();
  }
};
```

```css
:focus {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
Press Right/Left arrow keys to navigate
<ul id="mylist" tabindex="-1">
  <li tabindex="1">One</li>
  <li tabindex="2">Two</li>
  <li tabindex="4">Four</li>
  <li tabindex="3">Three</li>
  <li>Not selectable</li>
  <li tabindex="5">Five</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at https://github.com/luke-chang/js-spatial-navigation  It's a generic spatial navigation library.  It should be able to be integrated easily with Angular.

You may also want to check out this related SO: [Navigate the UI using only keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388021/navigate-the-ui-using-only-keyboard)

And this Angular TV app which purports to have spatial navigation:  https://github.com/ahmednuaman/angular-tv-app

Comment: I was trying to create a TV app using angular 4 but unable to use `js-spacial-navigation`. any thoughts on how to use it?

Comment: I don't know!  We (LG) created a fork of the library for use with our Enact framework.  It's called Spotlight and is available on npm here:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/@enact/spotlight  However, it's primarily for use with React.