# dropdown menu for angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

We have the below code for a dropdown menu which we use in Angular.js:

```
<div class="additional-features">
    <div class="event-update-label">Update Options</div>
    <div class="additional-features-item" ng-click="performOperation(1);">Action 1</div>
    <div class="additional-features-item" ng-click="performOperation(2);">Action 2</div>
    <div class="additional-features-item" ng-click="performOperation(3);">Action 3</div>
    <div class="additional-features-item" ng-click="performOperation(4);">Action 4</div>
</div>
```

With CSS it shows as a menu that the user can click on. The menu title is `Update Options` as shown in the first div. The problem is that the menu is **not** keyboard accessible. It requires a mouse click for all operations. How would I go about adding that accessibility to this menu? In jQuery it's not impossible, however, with angular i'm not sure how the directives would work in this situation. Can I have some guidance on how this would work? I have read the below:

https://github.com/jseppi/angular-dropdowns

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1931

[Navigate the UI using keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859970/navigate-the-ui-using-keyboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to use `jQuery` and simply do it from there. It's not the ideal solution, however, I was unable to make it work in a direct `angular.js` way.