# dropdown-toggle up and down keys in keyboard not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am unable to use up and down arrow buttons to focus on the drop down menu.
In my application, we are using angularjs.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="dropdown dropdown-eq2 form-group" dropdown>
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="icon-e_icon_expand pull-right" style="margin-left: 5px;">      </span>{{personObj.type}}
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu num-of-views" role="menu" dropdown-menu>
        <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="type in categoryArray">
            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="" ng-click="setSelectedType(type)">  {{type}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular UI dropdown don't support UP/DOWN keyboard navigation's.

You can build custom directive on top of this will full fill your requirement.

You can refer this link [Navigate the UI using keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859970/navigate-the-ui-using-keyboard)