# Is there a way to prevent backspace navigation in whole angularjs web application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to restrict backspace navigation in my whole app.Is there any solution i.e smething that i can do at one place for my whole app ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to stop browser back button using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript)

Comment: @dev ? Found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('yourModule', [])
  .controller('yourController', ['$scope', '$document', function($scope, $document) {
      $document.on('keydown', function(e){
          if(e.which === 8 && ( e.target.nodeName !== "INPUT" && e.target.nodeName !== "SELECT" ) ){ // you can add others here inside brackets.
              e.preventDefault();
          }
      });

    }
  ]);
```

It would prevent backspace navigation except for if any input tag is active.

We have not handled it for the textarea so it wouldn't allow backspace on textarea.

Here is the demo http://plnkr.co/edit/ZXtiJNI0a73c0SwIQ7mI?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper way:

```
preventNavigate.$inject = ['$window'];
function preventNavigate($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function() {
            $window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
               return "Are you sure you want to leave?"; 
            }
        }
    }
}

app.directive('preventNavigate', preventNavigate);
```

Then on your index.html after your ng-app include the attribute `prevent-navigate`;

```
<body ng-app="app" prevent-navigate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the keypress event directive like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19412163/6429253) and in the event callback you can `e.preventDefault();` if key pressed is backspace.